# How to set app:layout_scrollFlags for Toolbar programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

My app have a viewpager and 4 tabs, each tab have many fragment. But I just want my Toolbar scroll up/down while scrolling recyclerview in 2 specific tabs. But I don't know how to block Toolbar scroll for other tabs. I tried to import toolbar for each fragment but it seems I can't do it.
Anyone have idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend against changing the scrolling flags based on what tab is selected - having the Toolbar automatically return (and the content move down) when scrolling to a non-recyclerview tab can be very jarring and probably not an interaction pattern you want (exasperated if your two `RecyclerView` tabs are next to one another).

However, if you want to see it in person, you can use [setScrollFlags()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#setScrollFlags(int)) to set the scroll flags programmatically:

```
Toolbar toolbar = ... // your toolbar within an AppBarLayout
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
    | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
```

In order to clear flags

```
params.setScrollFlags(0)
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to make it that way but my stupid client want it :D.

Comment: Is it possible to let the scrolling work (meaning hide&show of elements, like the app-bar ) for ListView and other views that have scrolling?

Comment: It does make sense to play with scroll flags in specific scenarios like when entering search mode (Toolbar's ActionMode)

Comment: For me this worked partially but in order to enable/disable toolbar scrolling i followed the following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31167852/1118886)

Comment: If anyone want disable scrollflags programmatically use this : `params.setScrollFlags(0);`

Comment: +ianhanniballake I think that is need to change the scrolling flags in some cases as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39462310/4744263 Do you agree?

Comment: After support 25.3.1, it need to invoke `appBarLayout.requestLayout()` to take effects.

Comment: @Chaos - that shouldn't be necessary. If you have a sample project that works on an older version of the Support Library but doesn't in 25.3.1, please [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192731&template=842428)

Comment: How to remove these flags ??

Comment: @Chaos seems to be right. You have to call `#setLayoutParams(...)` on your view (which implicitly calls `requestLayout()`) or call it directly. Otherwise the changes won't have any effect.

Comment: Need to add `toolbar.setLayoutParams(params)`. setLayoutParams on toolbar is necessary for the changes to take effect especially when switching between setting and clearing scrollflags

Answer (score 15):

```
// Show toolbar when we are in maps mode
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) mToolbar.getLayoutParams();
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams appBarLayoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
if(isMapIndex) {
    params.setScrollFlags(0);
    appBarLayoutParams.setBehavior(null);
    mAppBarLayout.setLayoutParams(appBarLayoutParams);
} else {
    params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
    appBarLayoutParams.setBehavior(new AppBarLayout.Behavior());
    mAppBarLayout.setLayoutParams(appBarLayoutParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version for easy copy&paste. Should work with `core-ktx-1.8.0` lib

```kotlin
private fun SomeLayoutBinding.setScrollBehavior(enabled: Boolean) {
    appBarLayoutParams.updateLayoutParams<AppBarLayout.LayoutParams> {
        scrollFlags =
            if (enabled) AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL or AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS
            else 0
    }
}
```