# How to hide the Actionbar like they do in Whatsapp?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a fragment with following layout, to which I am adding two fragments with help of a view pager:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="#2096f3"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in the code:

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(tabs[0]));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(tabs[1]));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have a scrollview in the fragments in the view pager. I want the action-bar to hide when I start to scrolldown. How to achieve this?

I have a toolbar in the activity to which I am adding few fragments. How can I tweak it get the expected result:

Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:paddingTop="1dp"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
```

Comment: Did you even try googling? `android hide actionbar`

Comment: I tried hiding the action-bar when the user starts scrolling down. But the behavior was very abrupt.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [**this library**](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) and its sample.

gif animation:

[image: image.gif]

The sample file is  "[**ViewPagerTabScrollViewActivity**](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/observablescrollview-samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples/ViewPagerTabScrollViewActivity.java)"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom defined style for that:

```
<resources>
 <style name = "AppTheme" parent = "android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
 <style name = "HiddenActionBar" parent = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>

</resources>
```

And use it on your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
 android:icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
 android:label = "@string/app_name"
 android:theme = "@style/HiddenActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

This XML code works properly for me :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2096f3"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I don't have that toolbar. I am adding the tabs dynamically:
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));

Comment: @Panda as you said "you want action bar to hide" so you should have `Toolbar` in activity with `noActionBar`. As i have shown you the code.

Comment: thanks Vipul. 
This works. But as I am adding tabs up in the code, dynamically, is there a way to handle this from code?

Comment: tabs are generally added in code only, and there is way to add `scrollFlags` in your code but that way is really not appreciated. If my answer worked for you. please be sure to accept it by clicking on check button below my answer's vote area.

Comment: Can you please let me know the way to add scrollFlags in my code?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771156/how-to-set-applayout-scrollflags-for-toolbar-programmatically).

Comment: Thanks Vipul. But this answer also uses the toolbar inside AppBarLayout. Nothing for new Tab().