# Android: How to Programatically add app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" to LinearLayoutView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view

Any help on how to programatically set  scrollFlags to linear layout. I can add it to xml but need to change it programatically

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">




 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Comment: possibly duplicate question - please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771156/how-to-set-applayout-scrollflags-for-toolbar-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does have what you need, but however I'm gonna share what I know. In order to do it programmatically you have to do two ways that most common things that every android dev does. I recommend you using the following and I'll send you the documentation of it.

Documentation for the LinearLayout what Methods, Attributes, Constructors and etc. is using: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout

View Binding Documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding?hl=en

```
 <!--Add the id to identify what element you want to use-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll||exitUntilCollapsed">
```

The old way of initialize the LinearLayout is this:

```
private lateinit var linearLayoutView: LinearLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        linearLayoutView = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_view)
        //This is an example, will send a documentation for full attributes.
        linearLayoutView.scrollBarStyle
    }
```

The new way of doing is using the View Binding, instead of instantiate something from a view and then getting the id, it's less code and spend time:

In app-level module gradle, you add this feature in android:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Then the code will look like this:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
        setContentView(binding.root)
        
        binding.linearLayoutView.scrollBarStyle
    }
```

Comment: I can't use viewBinding on the project, I am looking for a better approach to solve it

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
   private fun enableDeviceScroll(enable: Boolean) {
       val params =  scrollView.layoutParams as AppBarLayout.LayoutParams
       if(enable){
        params.scrollFlags = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL)
       }else{
        params.scrollFlags = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    }
}
```